# What's wrong with this perl matching pattern?

Tags: regex, perl

For a svn precommit hook, I want to strip leading spaces (there are surely no tabs present) on lines with certain keywords in them before committing them to the server. For example the line

```
    MACRO_1 (ABC, "Some String");
```

shall be matched and the leading spaces before `MACRO_1` shall be removed. Currently, I have the following expression to match:

```
   if($line =~ /^\s+MACRO_1|MACRO_2|MACRO_3|MACRO_4.*/) {
     print "Stripping leading space on line $line\n";
     $line =~ s/^\s*//gsxm;   # strip leading spaces
   }
```

When I look at the console, I get the following output:

```
Stripping leading space on line MACRO_1;
Stripping leading space on line MACRO_2;
Stripping leading space on line     MACRO_3 (ABC, "Some String");
Stripping leading space on line  MACRO_1;
Stripping leading space on line MACRO_2;
Stripping leading space on line MACRO_1(123);
Stripping leading space on line MACRO_2(123);
Stripping leading space on line             MACRO_1;
Stripping leading space on line MACRO_2;
Stripping leading space on line MACRO_1;
```

This seems a bit confusing to me since there are lines with no leading space that I thought would not be matched by `\s+` which is in my opinion *one or more spaces*.

What's the problem?

Comment: None of those modifiers (`/gsxm`) are useful for the substitution you're doing (assuming that `$line` really does contain a single line).  In fact, they make it slower, since `/m` allows `^` to match after embedded newlines and `/g` means it has to look for another match.

Comment: Was a copy-and-paste line. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Using cut'n'paste code like that can be very dangerous.  Specifically, the `/x` modifier says to ignore whitespace in the regex.  The string "toy boat" does not match `/toy boat/x`, for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `|` has the *lowest precedence* among the regex operators.

So the following is an *incorrect* regex to match a string containing either only `foo` or  only `bar`:

```
^foo|bar$
```

because it'll be treated as:

```
(^foo)|(bar$)
```

which matches any string beginning with `foo` or ending in `bar`; so it matches for example `foo1` and `1bar`.

The correct regex would be `^(?:foo|bar)$`

Similarly in your case the correct regex is:

```
if($line =~ /^\s+(?:MACRO_1|MACRO_2|MACRO_3|MACRO_4).*/) {
```

Also note that there is no need of the trailing `.*`.

You can shorten your regex as:

```
if($line =~ /^\s+MACRO_[1-4]/) {
```

Comment: Well, if there are no leading spaces, then it doesn't _need_ to match, because there's nothing to strip.

Comment: @cjm: Right. I've mentioned that in my last sentence. Hard to see how his regex matched `MACRO_1;` which has no leading space. It is matching it because we see it in the output.

Comment: unless `$&` or `$'` are used, that trailing `.*` serves no purpose

Comment: What is the purpose of the ?: in if($line =~ /^\s+(?:MACRO_1|MACRO_2|MACRO_3|MACRO_4).*/) {
?

Comment: @freshWoWer: taken from http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns: *This is for clustering, not capturing; it groups subexpressions like "()", but **doesn't make backreferences as "()" does**.*